# Create a vpc with ruby-sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-vpc

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html

```
2.1.1 > require 'aws-sdk'
 => true
2.1.1 > AWS.config(
2.1.1 >       access_key_id:     "key",
2.1.1 >       secret_access_key: "key",
2.1.1 >       region:            "us-east-1",
2.1.1 >     )
 => <AWS::Core::Configuration>
```

I'm calling the contructor in irb:

```
2.1.1 > vpc = AWS::EC2::VPC.new('new-vpc')
 => <AWS::EC2::VPC id:new-vpc>
```

I am expecting to see a new vpc in my management account, yet I am not.

```
2.1.1 > vpc.state
AWS::EC2::Errors::InvalidVpcID::NotFound: The vpc ID 'new-vpc' does not exist
```

Can VPCs be created with the sdk?
Am I thinking about VPC the wrong way? I am trying to create a vpc so that I can connect to my company's vpn and our locally hosted git repos.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 2):

VPCs can be created with the SDK. Since this question was posted a [newer AWS SDK](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2NJE86FP0HHXX/Announcing-V2-of-the-AWS-SDK-for-Ruby) has been released. You can create a VPC using the following code, which takes advantage of the new and more intuitive [Resource](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx1H87IVGVUMIB5/Using-Resources) classes.

```
require 'aws-sdk'
Aws.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'}) # for example
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Resource.new
vpc = ec2.create_vpc({:cidr_block => '10.3.0.0/16'}) # for example
# => #<Aws::EC2::Vpc id="vpc-e6468682">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. That's how I made it work:

```
vpc = AWS::EC2::VPCCollection.new
vpc.create '192.168.1.119/24'
```

The logic behind class names still remains unclear to me though :)